# Using gulp-sass-glob in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sass, gulp, sass-globbing

In Visual Studio (Task Runner Explorer), I am trying to use gulp-sass-glob in my SCSS:

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  sassGlob = require('gulp-sass-glob');

gulp.task('css', function () {
  return gulp.src('./gulp/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sassGlob())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

**site.scss**

```
@import "modules/**/*.*";
```

But in Task Runner Explorer, I get the following error:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: modules/**/*.*
Parent style sheet: C:/Users/.../scss/site.scss
  on line 95 of gulp/scss/site.scss
  >> @import "modules/**/*.*";
```

Does anybody know how to fix this error or if this is even achievable when using SCSS and gulp in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

`gulp-sass-glob` uses the [`glob`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) package for path globbing. Its documentation [has this to say](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer) about `**`:

> `**` If a "globstar" is **alone in a path portion**, then it matches zero or more directories and subdirectories searching for matches.

Notice the bolded part. It means `**` only has special meaning when its the only thing between two slashes `/`.

Try the following in your **site.scss**:

```
@import "modules/**/*.*";
```